# CSS styles do not take effect

Tags: css

I'm using the subsequent code for a contact form on the following website http://fuel.social, and most of the styles I specified, like border-width and color don't apply. A hint would be much appreciated.

Many thanks for your time!

```
img.ajax-loader { display: none; }

div.wpcf7-response-output, div.wpcf7-validation-errors { display: none           !important; }
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip { display: none; }

.wpcf7-textarea,
.wpcf7-email {
border-width: 2px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #E8E8E8;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-style: italic;
}
```

Here's the code from the contact form:

```
<div id="form-container">
    LEAVE US A MESSAGE
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">[textarea* textarea-533 5/360 your-email placeholder "A maximum of 360 characters"]</div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">[email* email-104 class:form control placeholder "Your email address"]</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">[submit class:btn class:btn-primary "Send"]        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your related HTML codes as well ? If you want to check whether a CSS rule is overridden by other rules, you can review it in Developer Console.

Comment: Sure, here's the code from the contact form:

Comment: <div id="form-container">
    LEAVE US A MESSAGE
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">[textarea* textarea-533 5/360 your-email     placeholder "A maximum of 360 characters"]</div>
    <br>
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">[email* email-104 class:form-control     placeholder "Your email address"]</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">[submit class:btn class:btn-primary "Send"]        </div>
    </div>

Comment: No, please [edit] your question to include this information. (It's impossible to read it in the comment...)

Comment: Please update your codes in your question, instead of inside a comment

Comment: add id instead of class. this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getting overridden by:

```
.site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.site-content div.wpcf7 textarea {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-family: "courier-prime",monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 3px 0 0;
  padding: 6px 2% 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

in the same style file a few hundred lines before, because this (css) selector is more specific and kicks in.

**EDIT:** not really overridden but some kind of partial ignored for the already set properties ;)

You need to use the same or better a even more precise selector for your text, textarea and email field (e.g. ids)

Answer (score 0):

They don't apply because of this properties redefined in div.wpcf7 input[type='email']

Add !important to your class or use another selector for the element.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console and highlight the inputs to see which styles to overwrite.  Make sure the styles are at the end of the style sheet or you can replace in the style sheet around line 1724 where it currently is:

For instance, this is the css selector for the textarea, text inputs and email inputs (around line 1724):

```
 .site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="text"], 
 .site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="email"], 
 .site-content div.wpcf7 textarea {
 /* place your styles here */
 }
```

If you want to separate any of those, just do the following:

```
 .site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="text"]
 /* place your styles for text input here */
 }

 .site-content div.wpcf7 input[type="email"] {
 /* place your styles for email input here */
 }

 .site-content div.wpcf7 textarea {
 /* place your styles for text area here */
 }
```

Best...

Answer (score 0):

The rule on line 1724 will be applied because `.site-content div.wpcf7 textarea` is stronger selector than `.wpcf7-textarea`.

You better selector to overwrite rule on line 1724, eg. `.site-content .wpcf7-form .wpcf7-textarea` to avoid using `!important` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score -1):

Add `!important` to your class

```
border-width: 2px !important;
```

Comment: Whatever the question, `!important` is almost never the answer.

Comment: don't use `!important` unless you have very special reasons, which I can't think of one right now.

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.